# Prestashop hookActionProductCancel is not working

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm developing a payment module for Prestashop 1.7.7 and I want to add some functionalities to the hookActionProductCancel. I try to add it to my main my_module.php file but it's not working.

```php
public function hookActionProductCancel($params)
{
    Tools::dieObject($params);
}
```

Also, I register the hook with:

```php
public function install()
{
    return parent::install()
        && $this->registerHook('header')
        && $this->registerHook('displayPaymentReturn')
        && $this->registerHook('actionProductCancel')
        && $this->registerHook('paymentOptions');
}
```

Comment: **hookActionProductCancel** is 
called when a product is canceled in an order in 
*admin/AdminOrdersController.php* file.

Make sure you are expecting some action there and not elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Solved, It was a bug described here https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/20712 and its solved on the Prestashop version 1.7.7.1